# why cannot redefine a macro with previous value even using a temp variable?

Tags: c++, macros

for example,I have a macro string A="a", I want to append "b" to A, to become "ab", I tried

```
#define A "a"
#define A A "b"
```

and then found it seems become self referential macros which is not possible. I tried to hold the value of A "b" using a temp variable TEMP first, and then undefine A and then define A as TEMP:

```
#include <sstream>
#define A "a"
#define TEMP A "b"
#undef A
#define A TEMP
int main(){
    printf(A);
    return 0;
}
```

but it still cannot compile, why?

Comment: Macro definitions are not _variables_!

Comment: For `printf` you need to include `cstdio` and not `sstream`